# Paypal variables for Buy Now

Tags: php, paypal

I have a basket that I want to pass over to paypal. I have the standard variables - item_number, item_name, amount etc etc but I have a field called description but there are no variables in paypal to do with description?

What could I do? Is there a way to make a custom variable but still integrate it with paypal?

I have already had a look at: https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Description Here">

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the following:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value='Description'>
    <input type="hidden" name="os0" value='Your content'>
```

If on0 is omitted, no variable is passed back to you.

os0 :
 First set of option values. If this option is selected through a text
box or radio button, each value should be no more than 64
characters. If this value is entered by the customer in a text field,
there is a 200-character limit. If omitted, no variable is passed
back to you.

NOTE: on0 must also be defined set.